# Subprocess: "Exec format error" in gekko package

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am trying to run gekko in python 2 or 3. I simply followed a tutorial with changed parameters, and I utilized scipy.integrate to simulate my MPC. It works on one of my computer but not on my NVIDIA Jetson TX2. And got the "Exec format error" when running m.solve(disp=False).

Both computer have both python2 and python3. Since I am also running ROS, I would like to use python2 to run the script. Initially I thought it might be the using python2 to interpret is causing the problem, so i wrote another script utilizing subprocess to interpret my mpc and simulator as python3. However, this problem persist. The problem seems to be within gekko package. I am sure it is an environment error, since the script did run fine on my personal computer. Currently I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

```
def example_MPC(t_init, x, u_init):
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    dt = 0.5
    m.time = np.linspace(t_init,10+t_init,21)
    #...
    m.solve(disp=False)       # <-- The error appears on this line
    #...
    return p.value[1]
```

This is the error message from the terminal:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ode_solver.py", line 53, in <module>
    simulation()
  File "ode_solver.py", line 34, in simulation
    u[i] = example_MPC(t[i-1], v0, u[i-1])
  File ".../src/MPC_test.py", line 34, in example_MPC
    m.solve(disp=False)
  File "/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gekko/gekko.py", line 1880, in solve
    env = {"PATH" : self._path }, universal_newlines=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
  OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Edit:

I found the apm folder location. When I tried to run **apm** with

```
./apm
```

The command gives me this:

```
-bash: ./apm: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I am assuming this means on my TX2, apm is not running properly.

If I set `m = GEKKO(remote=True)`, it works. However, MPC is not able to run in real time, which is definitely a problem for me.

I am now trying to solve this problem on a local desktop. Is the server argument just the local ip address? I set:

```
m = GEKKO(remote=True, server="192.168.1.136")
```

It returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../src/ode_solver.py", line 53, in <module>
    simulation()
  File ".../src/ode_solver.py", line 34, in simulation
    u[i] = example_MPC(t[i-1], v0, u[i-1])
  File ".../src/MPC_test.py", line 34, in example_MPC
    m.solve(disp=False)
  File ".../.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gekko/gekko.py", line 1992, in solve
    raise ImportError('Results files not found. APM did not find a solution or the server is unreachable.')
ImportError: Results files not found. APM did not find a solution or the server is unreachable.
```

Setting `m = GEKKO(remote=True, server="http://192.168.1.136")` yield the same problem.

Comment: The error is coming from a failed attempt to launch a utility called `apm` (apmonitor).  I'm not familiar with this gekko package you're using, but I'd guess that you either don't have apm installed, or don't have it installed in the right place - check the installation instructions again.

Comment: I just installed apmonitor with: python3 -m pip install --user APMonitor and python -m pip install --user APMonitor. The problem still persist.

Comment: Could you try to run ./apm_arm instead of ./apm on the NVIDIA Jetson TX2. I think it is an ARM processor, correct? The apm executable is built for Linux on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: If you are trying to solve on a locally installed server, I recommend that you use the localhost address: http://127.0.0.1 If the local server computer is on your network then you should first verify that you can connect to that computer with "ping 192.168.1.136". You can also test the connection and that PHP and the Apache server are working by visiting http://192.168.1.136/ip.php from a client web-browser or use "wget http://192.168.1.136/ip.php" from the command line. It should show your client IP address.

Comment: A local server doesn't help the executable compatibility unless you are serving from a computer where the local executable can run. An example is to have a Windows or Linux server that solves the optimization problems for the NVIDIA Jetson TX2.

Comment: When I am trying to run ./apm_arm, terminal returned: `-bash: ./apm_arm: No such file or directory`. However, from terminal `ls` command, it is clearly there. For all other executable files, it only returns the exec format error. Is there a reason why? And I believe yes, TX2 does use ARM processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve remotely (requires Internet connection):

```py
m = GEKKO(remote=True)
```

or else set up a [Windows APMonitor Server](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/APMonitorServer) or a [Linux APMonitor Server](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/APMonitorServerLinux) and solve on that server (e.g. IP address 10.0.0.10) with:

```py
m = GEKKO(remote=True,server='http://10.0.0.10')
```

The problem is that there is no compatible executable for the NVIDIA Jetson TX2 hex-core ARMv8 64-bit CPU or else Python isn't picking the correct executable. You can see if the apm_arm executable will run on your computer by locating it in Lib/site-packages/gekko/bin or download from the [local executables](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/tree/master/gekko/bin) that are currently supported:

- Windows (32 or 64 bit): apm.exe
- Linux (64 bit): apm
- MacOS (64 bit): apm_mac
- Linux ARM (Raspberry Pi): apm_arm

If it doesn't run or isn't on this list then I recommend using `remote=True` with a local server or else the publicly available server. I added the NVIDIA Jetson TX2 local executable as a [feature request in the GEKKO repository on GitHub](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues/71).

Comment: I think apm_arm is a 32 bit executable, and TX2 is 64 bit. apm_arm is not running properly on TX2? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I think you are right. Raspberry Pi comes with a 64-bit chip but most OS versions are 32-bit. I would need to get a TX2 to compile the APM executable because it isn't open-source. I don't think there is a work-around right now unless you wanted to try a local server option such as https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/APMonitorServerLinux running on another computer in your lab and communicating with the TX2 over the Intranet.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you let me know if you ever fix this problem?

Comment: Sure, I'll let you know.